# Is there any way to remove this row from soft key board of android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a problem with this soft keyboard row.

I have tried a suggestion to remove this but it is not working.

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_bold"
          android:textColor="#ffffffff"
          android:textColorHint="#646363"
          android:privateImeOptions="nm"
          android:inputType="textPassword|textVisiblePassword" />
```

a red marked thing should be removed from a soft keyboard

[image: <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Yt3r6x4/Screenshot-1557750686.png"; alt="Screenshot-1557750686" width="920" height="174">]

Comment: You can't remove that. It is custom to the GBoard keyboard, not a standard component.

Comment: You do not control the soft keyboard. You can provide hints, as you are with `android:inputType`. Some keyboards will never have such a row. Some keyboards will always show such a row, despite your hints. Those decisions are up to the developers of the keyboards.

Comment: okay i see, is not there any way to remove or replace with number row so that it can be removed.

Comment: The only viable solution I see for that is creating your own keyboard. You can never have full control over software that runs outside of your app's scope.

Comment: @Tharkius That being correct, one should also never override user's selected keyboard. They are using it for purposes the developer knows nothing about. Someone using a keyboard designed for visually impaired or for limited finger mobility will be royally miffed if the developer forces them to use a keyboard that suits some limited idea of how a keyboard should look like.